# ZXing.Net.Mobile update crash on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing

I need help with ZXing.Net.Mobile component (barcode scanning library).

The latest versions produce a runtime error for Galaxy Ace 2 (API 10) device, not only in my application, but also in the sample included with the library.

I would like to know if this is a bug or just API limitation.

Tested version: 2.0.4.17. You can try sample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an API limitation. As you can see on this [link](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/276) the ZXing Scanner version was incompatible with some devices.

Fortunately, its creator solved it and he launched a new version compatible with Android 2.3.